# Extract specific js fragment from source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using ajax to get page source (successfully). Inside that source, there is a specific script inside SCRIPT tags, and inside it there is a definition of some data I need to get (var vName = [{...}]). The data is an array, a rather big one, and the variable name is fixed.

What would be the way to get this variable and make some kind of similar array based on data of that variable?

Answer (score 1):

If you're successfully getting the page source as text you can search the text of that file using a regular expression. The exact regular expression depends on how your data is setup. Here are a few good places to start:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/you-dont-know-anything-about-regular-expressions/
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

There are many more resources. If you control the page's source then I would suggest you put that variable you're searching for on a single line. That way you don't have to do any complicated parsing.

Edit:

Additionally, you can also use the `indexOf` method for strings to get the index in the text where the variable starts. That is assuming that the variable name is unique. `indexOf` is used like this:

```
var someString = "hello world";
console.log(someString.indexOf('world')) // This should output 6
```

Comment: no, I am not in control of the source, and the variable definition takes several lines

Comment: Ahh i see. Well, you'll still need to use regular expressions to do the parsing of each line.

Comment: @Astro I added an edit to also illustrate the use of `indexOf` which can be used as well, but you will still need to use regular expressions to do some further parsing. There is no simple solution.

Comment: I have taken out "accepted answer" because if a get the page source via $.get(url), somehow all SCRIPT tags are removed. Any suggestions on how to get page source with all script tags in it?

Comment: @Astro, this was not part of the original question so could you edit the original question and I'll try to answer it as well. I want to make sure others that need this will be able to use it. Also, what site are you grabbing the html from and what version of jquery are you using?